# It does the job on second click, why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a toggle function. It should show the hidden div on first click, and hide it on second click and so on... It works, however, when you click first, nothing happens. And when you click again, it does the job. (show on first click, hide on second click and so on...)

Html

```
<div id="kesfetust">Click me</div>
<div id="sis">I'm a hidden div, and I should open on the first click,
and hidden on the second click.</div>
```

Jquery

```
$("#kesfetust").click(function() {
  var clicks = $(this).data('clicks');
  if (clicks) {
$("#sis").css({display: 'block'});
  } else {
$("#sis").css({display: 'none'});
  }
  $(this).data("clicks", !clicks);
});
```

What is the correct way to make it work correctly, where did I made a mistake ?

Comment: Why those downvotes ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/j3tknhs7/ does seem to work for first click too

Comment: OP, do you ensure (in CSS maybe) #sis is initially hidden ?

Comment: The hidden div is not hidden when you display the page at first. ^^

Comment: Well... hide it ! You may do it in css or in js, as you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your div is not hidden initially, please hide this using `display:none`:

```
<div id="sis" style="display:none">I'm a hidden div, and I should open on the first click,
and hidden on the second click.</div>
```

Why not a simple and short one :

```
$("#kesfetust").click(function() {
    $("#sis").toggle();
});
```

Comment: Works like a charm. I couldn't believe how I missed that simplicity. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Because first time when you click,there is no `data("clicks")` in the div,so `clicks` will be `undefined`,and it will go into else case set the sis div hidden.

I suggest you do it in jquery way:

```
$("#kesfetust").click(function() {
    $("#sis").toggle();
}
```

Or if you insist on do it by yourself:

```
$("#kesfetust").click(function() {
     if($("#sis").is(":hidden"))
        $("#sis").show();
     else
        $("#sis").hide();
}
```